# What is the difference between web service producer and consumer?

Tags: java, web-services

I am used to the terms **Client** and **Service** (or Server) in web service.

Could you confirm me please which one it is web service **Producer** and **Consumer**?

And would you tell me why having 2 terms for the same meaning? I don't understand what my colleagues complain that the terms client/server causes confusion.

Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Client => Consumer** : a client is the one who consumes.

**Server => Producer** : the one who produces something to the client.

**Client / Server** is often used in architectural concepts, so it does not describe the WS itself, but the architectural pattern between the one on which you connect and the one who connect.
**Consumer/Producer** is more understandable since it describes the service architectural pattern. You have a part who gives a service, and an other part who uses it.

So Client / Server is more generical. Consumer / Producer is SOA specific.

Answer (score 1):

`Web Services for Remote Portlets(WSRP)` introduces the concepts of [Producers](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13218_01/wlp/docs81/wsrp/intro.html#1001252) and [Consumers](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13218_01/wlp/docs81/wsrp/intro.html#1004976).By using WSRP, you can aggregate application functionality by integrating WSRP-compliant Producers into WebLogic Portal as a Consumer. Your end users thus will be able to interface with Consumers to view the integrated applications.

**Fig .Web Services Between Producer and Consumer**
[image]

For more detail see [this](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13218_01/wlp/docs81/wsrp/intro.html) link.

Answer (score 0):

Even Though this question is off-topic...

U should know that:

**Client** => Consumer : as it consumes the service..

**Server** => Producer : as it produces the service data for consumer..

And we have 2 words one for naive and one for technical user...

Hope my answer clears you...

Many thanks,...

Comment: Can you explicit the one for naive and the other technical user?

Comment: @Julia I think he's wrong. This is not naive but more generic. CF the edition of my answer.

Comment: Thank you both for the answers +1.

Comment: So if you have a wsdl link and you want to obtain data. you're consuming right?